# Newbie AngularJS Controller $scope cannot read property of undef

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to solve a problem obviously some of the newbies with Angular experience sometimes. Even there are several posts I did not find the problem with my small example. Scenario:

- webpage that shows comments & a rating.
- the site provides the possibility to enter a new comment/rating
- javascript should push the new entry into the array of existing comments
- there easily could be one Controller for the whole story, but it was the intention to learn about the 'inheritance' model of controllers, so there's by intention two small controllers

Problem:

- the function(in controller2) which pushes the new entry to the array of 
  existing comments(controller 1) results in a TypeError, because the array in this scope is undefined.

```html
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp', [])

        .controller('DataController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.comments = [{rating: 1, comment:"bla", author: "pma", date: new Date().toISOString()} , {rating:2, comment:"harakiri", author:"hku", date: new Date().toISOString()}];
        }])

        .controller('CommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.comment = {rating:5, comment:"", author:"", date: new Date().toISOString() };

            $scope.submitComment = function () {
                console.log($scope.comment);
                $scope.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();

                // this scope here does not know about the comments array --> BUG                
                $scope.comments.push($scope.comment);
                $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
                $scope.comment = {rating:5, comment:"", author:"", date: new Date().toISOString()};
                console.log($scope.comment);
            };
        }])

;
```

the HTML page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DataController">
                  <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                      <blockquote ng-repeat="comment in comments | orderBy: sortOption">
                        <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
                        <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                        <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date}}</footer>
                      </blockquote>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="CommentController">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
                  <!-- name property -->
                  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : commentForm.author.$error.required || commentForm.author.$pristine }">
                      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="comment.author" required>
                        <span ng-show="commentForm.author.$error.required || commentForm.author.$pristine" class="help-block">Your name is required</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- the rating -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rating" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rating</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="ratingGroup" id="inlineRadio1" ng-model="comment.rating" value="1"> 1
                      </label>
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="ratingGroup" id="inlineRadio1" ng-model="comment.rating" value="2"> 2
                      </label>
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="ratingGroup" id="inlineRadio1" ng-model="comment.rating" value="3"> 3
                      </label>
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="ratingGroup" id="inlineRadio1" ng-model="comment.rating" value="4"> 4
                      </label>
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="ratingGroup" id="inlineRadio1" ng-model="comment.rating" value="5"> 5
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- the comments -->
                  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : commentForm.comment.$error.required || commentForm.comment.$pristine }">
                      <label for="feedback" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comment</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="12" ng-model="comment.comment" placeholder="Please provide some comments" required></textarea>
                          <span ng-show="commentForm.comment.$error.required || commentForm.comment.$pristine" class="help-block">Your comment is required !</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- the button -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Send Comments</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

thank you, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: One way you can do is to broadcast a event with your comment in your second controller to first controller using $broadcast service(This broadcasts to your rootscope).In your first controller register a $on event to check for the broadcasted event.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it is **one controller per view**. You have two controllers in the same view: DataController and CommentController.

The array should be stored in a Service (injecting it in both controllers; CommentController adds a comment to the service's array; the DataController reads from it).

Things get complicated when ng-click (CommentController) triggers an event which normally should refresh the array used in DataController.

The proper way is to use only one controller.

Here is how I set up a service for the array:

```
.service('CommentService', function() {
  var comments = [
    {rating: 1, comment:"bla", author: "pma", date: new Date()}, 
    {rating:2, comment:"harakiri", author:"hku", date: new Date()}
  ];

  return {
    comments: comments
  }
})
```

http://codepen.io/nadeemramsing/pen/QGmzbV?editors=1111

(solution incomplete though; just use a single controller)

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn about inheriting controller scope. Where you have gone wrong in your example is that CommentController is not actually a child controller of DataController and therefore will not inherit the scope.

You therefore need to ensure that in your HTML the DataController is a parent of the CommentController. The simple way to achieve this is to move the DataController to the body element:

```
<body ng-controller="DataController">
```